# Run parallel Stata do files in python using multiprocess and subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing, stata

I have a stata do file pyexample3.do, which uses its argument as a regressor to run a regression. The F-statistic from the regression is saved in a text file. The code is as follows:

```
clear all
set more off        
local y `1'        
display `"first parameter: `y'"'

sysuse auto
regress price `y'
local f=e(F)
display "`f'"
file open myhandle using test_result.txt, write append
file write myhandle "`f'" _n
file close myhandle
exit, STATA clear
```

Now I am trying to run the stata do file in parallel in python and write all the F-statistics in one text file. My cpu has 4 cores.

```
    import multiprocessing
    import subprocess

    def work(staname):
        dofile = "pyexample3.do"
        cmd = ["StataMP-64.exe","/e", "do", dofile,staname]
        return subprocess.call(cmd, shell=False)

    if __name__ == '__main__':

        my_list =[ "mpg","rep78","headroom","trunk","weight","length","turn","displacement","gear_ratio" ]

        my_list.sort()

        print my_list

        # Get the number of processors available
        num_processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

        threads = []

        len_stas = len(my_list)

        print "+++ Number of stations to process: %s" % (len_stas)

        # run until all the threads are done, and there is no data left

        for list_item in my_list:

            # if we aren't using all the processors AND there is still data left to
            # compute, then spawn another thread

            if( len(threads) < num_processes ):

                p = multiprocessing.Process(target=work,args=[list_item])

                p.start()

                print p, p.is_alive()

                threads.append(p)

            else:
                for thread in threads:

                if not thread.is_alive():

                   threads.remove(thread)
```

Although the do file is supposed to run 9 times as there are 9 strings in my_list, it was only run 4 times. So where went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `for list_item in my_list` loop, after the first 4 processes get initiated, it then goes into `else`:

```
for thread in threads:
    if not thread.is_alive():
        threads.remove(thread)
```

As you can see since `thread.is_alive()` won't block, this loop get executed immediately without any of those 4 processes finishing their task. Therefore only the first 4 processes get executed in total.

You could simply use a `while` loop to constantly check process status with a small interval:

```
keep_checking = True

while keep_checking:
    for thread in threads:
        if not thread.is_alive():
           threads.remove(thread)
           keep_checking = False

    time.sleep(0.5) # wait 0.5s
```

Comment: Now the do files is run 7 times, but still 2 times are missing. The number also changes when 0.5s is changed. Is it caused by the simultaneous write to the text file?

Comment: It could be. Since writing to a same file is not thread-safe, which means if you write to a file from different processes at a same time, there might be unexpected results, so you might want to use `RLock` to make sure there's only one process working on the file at a same time.